# Protractor - Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, protractor, mjs

Using protractor and trying to switch to using es6 `import` instead of commonjs `require` approach

- I changed `package.json` and added (in the top section)  `"type": "module"`
- I renamed my two app files from `.js` to `.mjs`
- I changed my protractor `conf.js` to be `conf.mjs`
- I changed my protractor conf file to use `specs: ['spec.mjs']` as the test file to run
- I changed my conf file extension from `.js` to `.cjs`
- I changed the require to be `import { httpGet } from './support'`
- I tried `--experimental-modules` but that gave an error with above setup

However when I run

```
protractor conf.mjs
```

I get

Must use import to load ES Module

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I get this problem with nodejs 12 and nodejs 14 but not with nodejs 10.